# SqlDataReader to read into List<Class>

Tags: c#, windows-services, sqlconnection

i debug the windows Service, when i reach the while(rdr.read()) it doesn't enter the block code implementation it directly goes to constructors and get the data here is my project:

main project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Transactions;
using newsService.Entities;

namespace newsService
{
public partial class newsService : ServiceBase
{
    protected System.Timers.Timer feedGathererTimer;

    public newsService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        feedGathererTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        feedGathererTimer.Interval = 600000; //900000;
        feedGathererTimer.Enabled = false;
        feedGathererTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(feedGathererTimer_Elapsed);
    }

    private void feedGathererTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the list of feeds that we will poll
        try
        {
            List<FeedMidSpor> feedListMidSpor = FeedMidSpor.GetList();
            List<FeedLebSpor> feedListLebSpor = FeedLebSpor.GetList();
            List<FeedWodSpor> feedListWodSpor = FeedWodSpor.GetList();


            foreach (FeedMidSpor feed in feedListMidSpor)
            {
                List<PostMidSpor> postListMidSpor = PostMidSpor.GetNewRssPostsFromUrl(feed);
                using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    if (feed.LastPostGuidNameChanged)
                        feed.Update();
                    if (postListMidSpor.Count > 0)
                        foreach (PostMidSpor post in postListMidSpor)
                            post.Add();

                    ts.Complete();
                }
            }

            foreach (FeedLebSpor feed in feedListLebSpor)
            {
                List<PostLebSpor> postListLebSpor = PostLebSpor.GetNewRssPostsFromUrl(feed);
                using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    if (feed.LastPostGuidNameChanged)
                        feed.Update();
                    if (postListLebSpor.Count > 0)
                        foreach (PostLebSpor post in postListLebSpor)
                            post.Add();

                    ts.Complete();
                }
            }

            foreach (FeedWodSpor feed in feedListWodSpor)
            {

                // Go get the posts for each feed
                List<PostWodSpor> postListWodSpor = PostWodSpor.GetNewRssPostsFromUrl(feed);

                using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    // if the Feed and its Guid changed, update the feed
                    if (feed.LastPostGuidNameChanged)
                        feed.Update();

                    // If it has posts, add them
                    if (postListWodSpor.Count > 0)
                        foreach (PostWodSpor post in postListWodSpor)
                            post.Add();

                    ts.Complete();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { string x = ex.Message; throw; }
        }


    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        feedGathererTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        feedGathererTimer.Enabled = false;
    }
}
}
```

feedMidSpor page where i getlist:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;


namespace newsService.Entities
{
[Serializable]
public class FeedMidSpor : BaseEntity
{
    #region Fields

    private string title;
    private string url;
    private string lastPostGuidName;
    private bool lastPostGuidNameChanged = false;


    #region Constructors

    public FeedMidSpor()
    {
    }

    public FeedMidSpor(int id, DateTime createdDate, string title, string url, string lastPostGuidName)
        : base(id, createdDate)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.url = url;
        this.lastPostGuidName = lastPostGuidName;
        this.lastPostGuidNameChanged = false;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public string Url
    {
        get { return url; }
        set { url = value; }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

    public string LastPostGuidName
    {
        get { return lastPostGuidName; }
        set
        {
            if (lastPostGuidName != value)
                this.lastPostGuidNameChanged = true;
            lastPostGuidName = value;
        }
    }

    public bool LastPostGuidNameChanged
    {
        get { return lastPostGuidNameChanged; }
        set { lastPostGuidNameChanged = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public void Update()
    {
        string connectionString1 = "Data Source=RAYYAN-THINK;Initial Catalog=newsProject;uid=rayyan1;password=rayyan@101;Connect Timeout=30";
        string sql = "UPDATE FeedMidSporRss SET LastPostGuidName = @lastPostGuidName, Title = @title,  Url = @url WHERE ID = @ID";
        using (SqlConnection cn1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString1))
        {

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn1))
            {
                cn1.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastPostGuidName", this.lastPostGuidName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", this.title);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", this.url);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", this.Id);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn1.Close();
            }
            // reset the flag
            this.lastPostGuidNameChanged = false;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Static Methods

    public static List<FeedMidSpor> GetList()
    {
        List<FeedMidSpor> feedList1 = new List<FeedMidSpor>();
        string connectionString = "Data Source=RAYYAN-THINK;Initial Catalog=newsProject;uid=rayyan1;password=rayyan@101;Connect Timeout=30";
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT ID, Title, Url, LastPostGuidName, DateCreated FROM FeedMidSporRss ORDER BY Sequence";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                try
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
feedList1.Add(new FeedMidSpor(Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]), Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["DateCreated"].ToString()), rdr["Title"].ToString(), rdr["Url"].ToString(), rdr["LastPostGuidName"].ToString()));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { string x = ex.Message; }

            }
        }
        return feedList1;
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

the abstract baseintity class is:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace newsService
{
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    #region Fields

    private int id;
    private DateTime createdDate;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    protected BaseEntity()
    {
    }

    protected BaseEntity(int id, DateTime createdDate)
    {
        this.id = (id != null) ? 0 : id;
        this.createdDate = (createdDate != null) ? createdDate = DateTime.MinValue  :createdDate;
    }

    #endregion


    #region Properties

    public DateTime CreatedDate
    {
        get { return createdDate; }
        set { createdDate = value; }
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

iam using windows service c#

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please specify it..

Comment: You create a new DataReader object on this line: `SqlDataReader rdr = new SqlDataReader();`. Then you throw that DataReader away on the line that follows, without ever using it. Don't do that.

Comment: ok the problem is  I've been inserting breakpoints in and trying to debug the code inside the while(rdr.read()) but it doesn't enter the code, it directly goes to constructors and get the data from database so the feedlist1 isn't adding any data

Comment: @joel Coehoorn i tried that i deleted this code and nothing happen still not entering the block code inside while(rdr.read())

Comment: What do you mean with _"it directly goes to constructors and get the data from database"_?

Comment: @CodeCaster when i debug and reach to while (rdr.read()) it goes directly to constructors:
            this.title = title;
            this.url = url;
            this.lastPostGuidName = lastPostGuidName;
            this.lastPostGuidNameChanged = false;

Comment: Those are not constructors but assignments. I don't see `this.title = title` in your code.

Comment: @CodeCaster My guess is that he means assignments in the constructor of FeedMidSpor(), which means a null exception is probably being thrown there.

Comment: here i edited the code this is the page
@DavidL i don't think that there is null exception because rdr is reading all the rows in the FeedMidSporRss table

Comment: @ra22: according to your code it should goto constructor inside while() loop, but here quetion is : are you getting the proper data from database or not?

Comment: @Sudhakar yes iam getting the propper data from database since iam reading the records in the Locals

Comment: @ra22: so whatis the exact problem you are facing here? sorry i could not understand,

Comment: @Sudhakar i can't enter the while block code it reaches the while(rdr.read()) and then goes directly to the assignments in the constructor and gives the data it is weird!!

Comment: @ra22: please check the answer and let me know if you need some thing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i really want first to thank @Sudhakar and every one who share his ideas for helping me but the solution was far from code error. Finally there is error in the project building so i clean the project and then build the project i uninstall newsService then install it another time and my project is running perfectly !!!

Answer (score 0):

you need to perform the proper check before assigning the values in constructor:

This:

```
public FeedMidSpor(int id, DateTime createdDate, string title, string url, string lastPostGuidName)
        : base(id, createdDate)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.url = url;
        this.lastPostGuidName = lastPostGuidName;
        this.lastPostGuidNameChanged = false;
    }
```

Should be  :

```
public FeedMidSpor(int id, DateTime createdDate, string title, string url, string lastPostGuidName)
        : base(id, createdDate)
    {
        this.title = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(title))?"":title;
        this.url = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(url))?"":url;
        this.lastPostGuidName = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastPostGuidName))?"":lastPostGuidName ;
        this.lastPostGuidNameChanged = false;
    }
```

Base class should be as below:

```
protected BaseEntity(int id, DateTime createdDate)
    {
        this.id = (id != null) ? id : 0;
        this.createdDate = (createdDate != null) ? createdDate : DateTime.MinValue  ;
    }
```

Comment: how to put int id and datetime createdDate like that

Comment: you mean : you want to insert id and createddatetime in constructor as other paramaters?

Comment: you dont need to initialise here as you are calling base class constructor using :base(id,createdDate) it will be invoked by default, if possible please share the base class constructor code also.

Comment: i need to check if they are null

Comment: yes thats why please share the  baseintity abstract class constructor which takes 2 parameters so that i will add a null check there also.

Comment: ok i will and really thanks for helping me i really appreciate it

Comment: No problems :) carry on.

Comment: is this code right?!! this.id = (id != null) ? 0 : id;
        this.createdDate = (createdDate != null) ? createdDate = DateTime.MinValue  :createdDate;

Comment: Please check my edited answer, your modifications are in reverse if value is not null then we should assign value otherwise we should assign default value.

Comment: i try it and nothing wrong with the assignments, they are not null and giving me the exact records but it wasn't entering the feedlist1.add(...) when it reaches while(rdr.read()) { opening brackets it goes directly to assign values to variables in constructors so the list (feedlist1) isn't adding any records the count is still 0

Comment: so what is the result?

Comment: How are you checking wether list is having items or not, could you please share the Main method class from where you are calling this GetList()

Comment: here it is @Sudhakar
maybe because the method public static List<FeedMidSpor> GetList() is static?!!

Comment: how are you confirming that you are not getting the items into list?

Comment: mmm so why it is skipping the feedlist1.Add(...)?

Comment: because the feedlist1.count is still 0 and feedListMidSpor.count is still 0 after getting list

Comment: do onethingg put a breakpoint in List<FeedMidSpor> feedListMidSpor = FeedMidSpor.GetList(); statement and see wether feedListMidSpor  contains any items or not?

Comment: Please move extended discussion to [chat], thanks :)